# How to set LastPasswordChangeTimestamp?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-powershell

We are using 3rd-party IdP for Office 365 (Azure AD) without Active Directory and some users are required frequent login. It looks [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/4025960/federated-users-in-azure-ad-are-forced-to-sign-in-frequently) matches our situation.
So, I wanted to set **LastPasswordChangeTimestamp** but failed even by **Set-MsolUser** powershell command. The command finished without errors but actually the value was not changed.

How can I set **LastPasswordChangeTimestamp** by powershell or rather API?

Comment: What was the error you received from `Set-MsoIUser`?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT The command said nothing, looked went well but the value was not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are having the same problem. The Azure Support said that setting this property is not supported anymore due to internal design changes and suggested us to go for https://feedback.azure.com to provide a design change request.

You can find the request here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/30930691-possibility-to-set-attribute-lastpasswordchangetim

Comment: Thank you. As @jason-ye-msft mentioned I'll do a little more investigation.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I set LastPasswordChangeTimestamp by powershell or rather API?

Based on my knowledge, we **can't** modify this attribute. This attribute sync with Azure.

After we change user's password, this attribute will update to new date.

This attribute `LastPasswordChangeTimestamp` used for **report** and **audit**, we can't update it manually.

Comment: Thank you for reply. The article I posted above says there are 2 ways to update.  One is from powershell that I failed  and the other is via Azure AD connect. The latter is useless because I don't use AD. So, there are no way to avoid this frequent login.

Comment: @TakehikoKodama this attribute was the time of change password, I think there are no way to change it:)

Comment: I think it should be done at last from 3rd-party IdP *or* other solution would be Azure AD stop referring this value for token lifetime.

Comment: @TakehikoKodama Maybe we can set user never expire, `Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName alias -PasswordNeverExpires $true`.

Comment: @jason-ye-msft Interesting. I've just set it to a user. I'll see how it goes, thank you.